# Invariant Violation: Picker has been removed from React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-picker

[image]

> ERROR  Invariant Violation: Picker has been removed from React Native.
> It can now be installed and imported from
> '@react-native-picker/picker' instead of 'react-native'.
> See https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker
> ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module
> (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the
> application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when
> the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error
> when loading React Native.

I'm trying to configure an existing react-native project, but I'm facing the above issue with it.

I do not have picker in the project while it is showing following error. Added @react-native-picker/picker as well.

Answer (score 2):

1.Install patch-package into your project,

Install @react-native-picker/picker into your project,

go to node_modules\react-native\index.js

replace all

```
invariant(
      false,
     'DatePickerAndroid has been removed from React Native. ' +
       "It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native- 
     community/datetimepicker' instead of 'react-native'. " +
       'See https://github.com/react-native- 
   datetimepicker/datetimepicker',
      );
```

or

```
invariant(
             false,
          ........ DatePicker ..........
             );
```

to

```
return require('@react-native-picker/picker')
```

run

```
npx patch-package react-native
```

rebuild your app and it will be work

Comment: This was part of the path that worked for me. I also needed to change the require() in 
ToolbarAndroidNativeComponent.js (within @react-native-community/toolbar-android) to an import, and patch that package also. The final import looks like:

import requireNativeComponent from 'react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/requireNativeComponent'

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In My case I removed @davidgovea/react-native-wheel-datepicker this package which uses old dependencies which caused the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It was released a fix in the version 2.15.2 of native-base.

history:
https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/pull/3230
https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/releases/tag/v2.15.2