# Picker has been removed from React Native. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-picker/picker'

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

PLEASE HELP!!I have search the entire project which DOES NOT use Pricker at all but when I run npx react-native run-android it throws out :

> ERROR Invariant Violation: Picker has been removed from React Native.
> It can now be installed and imported from
> '@react-native-picker/picker' instead of 'react-native'. See
> https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker ERROR Invariant
> Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module
> (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the
> application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when
> the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error
> when loading React Native.

Same problem faced by this guy at the below link...No answer available... Please help...Thank you in advance

[Invariant Violation: Picker has been removed from React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70138001/invariant-violation-picker-has-been-removed-from-react-native)

I have @react-native-picker/picker installed

This is my package.json

```
  "name": "MYAPP",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "build-android": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output iOS/main.jsbundle --platform 'android' --assets-dest ./  --dev false --reset-cache",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "postinstall": "npx jetify",
    "extractLangs": "react-gettext-parser --output messages.pot 'src/**/*.js'"
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.11",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.2.1",
    "axios": "0.24.0",
    "base-64": "1.0.0",
    "date-fns": "2.27.0",
    "gettext.js": "git+https://github.com/freiserg/gettext.js.git",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.3",
    "react-native-device-info": "8.4.8",
    "react-native-eject": "0.1.2",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "0.12.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.9.5",
    "react-native-navigation": "7.24.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "3.3.0",
    "react-native-swipeout": "2.3.6",
    "react-native-swiper": "1.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "9.0.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-redux": "7.2.6",
    "redux": "4.1.2",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "2.4.1",
    "shitty-qs": "1.0.1",
    "tcomb-form-native": "0.6.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "27.4.5",
    "enzyme": "3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.15.6",
    "eslint": "8.4.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "19.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.27.1",
    "jest": "27.4.5",
    "jetifier": "2.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "nock": "13.2.1",
    "react-gettext-parser": "1.16.0",
    "react-native-mock": "0.3.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "redux-mock-store": "1.5.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "verbose": true,
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/__tests__/mocks/global.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "**/__tests__/**/*.spec.js?(x)"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Install `@react-native-picker/picker`
2. Upgrade `"native-base": "2.15.2"`

Comment: not working bro

Comment: @ZeeshanAli did you resolve it? have same issue

Comment: @Lal Yes i solve

Comment: for my side i was upgrade latest version `native-base` and also upgrade `@react-native-picker/picker` latest version my issue was solve

Answer (score 0):

Officially picker has been removed from react-native. You can use the community edition. @react-native-community/picker

Comment: It's not working I uninstall @react-native-picker/picker and install @react-native-community/picker but I am still getting  ERROR Invariant Violation: Picker has been removed from React Native. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-picker/picker' instead of 'react-native'. I search my entire project for use of Pricker but I couldn't find any Pricker usage

Comment: @react-native-community/picker has been deprecated library has been renamed to @react-native-picker/picker which I have installed but I am still getting error

Comment: @runner366 are you resolved the error?

Answer (score 0):

Delete node modules folder then run `yarn install` at the terminal in your projects directory.

Then try to run the app again.

I am not sure this will help but since it says *This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.* it might be worth trying.

Comment: I have done that too not working..The funny thing is Picker is NOT used is this project..so where the error come from..

Comment: did you solve it  this error ?

Comment: @Zeeshan Ali are  you resolved the error?

Comment: @hamzeh-hanandeh Yes

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `tcomb-form-native` caused this error because it has not been updated for years. I hope this PR will be merged soon.
https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native/pull/605

Answer (score 0):

1.Install [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) into your project,

2. Install [@react-native-picker/picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-picker/picker) into your project,
3. go to `node_modules\react-native\index.js`
4. replace all

   ```
   invariant(
         false,
        'DatePickerAndroid has been removed from React Native. ' +
          "It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native- 
        community/datetimepicker' instead of 'react-native'. " +
          'See https://github.com/react-native- 
      datetimepicker/datetimepicker',
         );
   ```

or

```
 invariant(
             false,
          ........ DatePicker ..........
             );
```

to

```
 return require('@react-native-picker/picker')
```

run `npx patch-package react-native`

rebuild your app and it will be work